# How to Divide A String into 10 Variables

Tags: php, variables

Suppose i have a variable which carry a string, something like this:

```
$data="Fusce massa leo, pharetra sit amet tempus vitae, gravida nec est. Suspendisse at commodo sapien. Duis purus tortor, porttitor nec viverra ut, tempus at justo. Curabitur aliquam, odio non rhoncus aliquet, nulla felis laoreet lacus, sit amet facilisis nunc orci nec erat. Sed interdum, tellus in venenatis vehicula, tortor mauris gravida nisl, eget elementum tortor libero vulputate urna. Nullam euismod porta quam eu imperdiet. Aenean sit amet mauris mauris, id facilisis lectus. Cras sed diam ut nisl imperdiet mattis non a lorem. Nullam iaculis, est id vulputate dictum, odio odio elementum neque, vestibulum dapibus urna nibh vitae lectus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas hendrerit aliquet erat, sit amet tincidunt mauris pulvinar a. Vestibulum porta nulla ut nulla sodales mattis. Curabitur congue, metus sit amet commodo aliquam, eros elit semper nisl, a imperdiet quam diam id neque.

Nam at urna non lorem varius ultricies. Nullam nec pellentesque justo. Nulla lobortis rhoncus enim, vitae blandit augue malesuada sed. Etiam enim risus, volutpat at malesuada ac, placerat sit amet ante. Nam faucibus quam a nunc interdum ultrices. Vivamus eleifend lacus et dui rhoncus semper. Curabitur tempor velit ut mi luctus a feugiat neque feugiat. Proin condimentum aliquam placerat. In non tortor sed tortor interdum aliquam non tempus purus. Aenean rhoncus lobortis eros, ac gravida justo porta ut. Etiam ullamcorper ante sit amet eros lacinia pulvinar vitae non orci. Curabitur orci massa, ultricies id sodales eu, congue vel lectus. Cras a scelerisque nisl. Nulla ornare ultrices nisl, non viverra quam ornare quis.
Aenean non libero non ante cursus ultricies. Morbi tincidunt volutpat diam, quis interdum dolor tempus sed. Sed accumsan auctor est vel imperdiet. Proin auctor congue risus in pharetra. Ut faucibus luctus diam, at vehicula justo pulvinar id. Aliquam ipsum augue, hendrerit ultrices dapibus eu, hendrerit in tellus. Phasellus accumsan, ante eget sodales venenatis, nisl nibh pellentesque odio, a sodales mi eros eu ante. Phasellus a ipsum erat.";
```

Now i want to use a array and divide the data that comes from the variable `$data` to: `$mdata[0]`, `$mdata[1]` `$mdata[2]` `$mdata[3]`, `$mdata[4]` `$mdata[5]` `$mdata[6]`, `$mdata[7]` `$mdata[8]` `$mdata[9]` thoroughly from top to bottom in an equal parentage of data comes from the variable `$data`.
For example: `$mdata[0]` will contain
 `Fusce massa leo, pharetra sit amet tempus vitae, gravida nec est. Suspendisse at commodo sapien. Duis purus tortor`
And continuously for other variables of that array ... Any idea?

Comment: Split the string at the spaces with `explode`, count the resulting array items, divide the result by 10, get your 10 sub arrays with `array_chunk`, and put the words back together with `implode`.

Comment: Are you saying you want to (*please* don't type "wanna") divide the string into 10 equal lengths and assign each substring to an array element?

Comment: you want an equal number of WORDS in each of the sub-10, or a mostly-equal number of CHARACTERS?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard uh! sorry for that ,, yes you got the point... thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the length of the string, divide length by 10 and str_split it if you want each array item to contain an equal number of characters.

```
$length = strlen($data);
$mdata  = str_split($data, $length / 10);
```

If you want each array item to contain an equal number of words, not characters, this should work:

```
$words = explode(' ', $data);
$wseg  = floor(count($words) / 10);
$mdata = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
    $mdata[$i] = implode(' ', array_slice($words, $wseg * $i, $wseg));
}

$mdata[$i] = implode(' ', array_slice($words, $wseg * $i));
```

Comment: +1 for quick 'n dirty, but -1 for chopping words into pieces...so 0 overall.

Comment: @MarcB His question was ambiguous and I read it as wanting 10 equal length strings.